# prism mvvm server and client with same model

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, prism

my server is using an assembly (model.dll) which contains all model classes.
I would like to use these classes within my UWP-Client-App using MVVM.

In MVVM all my model-classes have to inherit BindableBase(Prism).
Is there a way to use the same model-classes in my Client or do I have to create them again especially for the Client?

The only way I can see is that all model-classes inherits BindableBase but I on the Server I don't need this dependency...

Comment: Do you need `BindableBase` or rather `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Requiring the model (or even the view model) to derive from `BindableBase` sounds strange, while a model that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` is quite nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to use the classes on both server and client, I suppose you're looking into putting them into a PCL (Portable Class Library) so you only have 1 file to maintain for each model. This implies that all code you want on the client, will be available on the server as well.

Prism's [`BindableBase`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs) is nothing more than a helper implementation for `INotifyPropertyChanged`. So you can either user `BindableBase` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` yourself. Either way, you'll have some 'frontend' code on your backend.

Note that to be able to use `BindableBase`, you don't have auto-properties, but property setters to trigger `INotifyPropertyChanged` (same when you implement the interface yourself).

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
}
```

What I typically do is create a PCL for my models, add [Prism.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Core/) NuGet package (which is a PCL itself) and live with the 'frontend' code on my server. If you want to know what code is in Prism.Core, that's everything under the [Source/Prism folder](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source/Prism). You don't need to bring in Prism.Windows in the server side.

---

What are your alternatives?

- Write all models twice, once with auto properties for the server and once with BindableBase/INotifyPropertyChanged for the client. I give it less than a week before your models are inconsistent. Tou counter that, you could go for code (re-)generation to generate one of both sides.
- Use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/UniversalAppSample/) for INotifyPropertyChanged instead of Prism's `BindableBase`, you can keep using the rest of Prism. But in my opinion this has the same problem, bringing Fody's attribute to the server.
- Use linked project files to share the models between server and client, so the files still exist only once. Make every class partial, place a second partial class in the client and put Fody's attribute on that definition. Looks like quite a hassle to me.

Conclusion: whether you're using Prism or Fody, learn to live with that small dependency on the server side which brings the great advantage of a single model.

Comment: thank you Bart. That is what I wanted to read :) My Model-Class is a .NET Standard 1.4 (UWP only Supports this Version). Is there an Advantage of using PCL over .NET Standard? I thought .NET Standard is the "new" way of sharing libraries.

Comment: .NET Standard is the way forward, we're however waiting for v 2.0 on most of the projects before we're moving (mainly because of the covered APIs). If 1.4 brings enough coverage for you, nothing prevents you from using .NET Standard.